# Laravel "any" Routing Security

Tags: php, laravel, csrf-protection

Let's say I have a products page loaded with GET method.
I am filtering these products with POST method, returns to the same page.
**The question is** if the following approach is safe from csrf or any other injection methods?
**Note that** i'm using laravel 5.2 and have to include csrf function in my post forms.

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('products', array(
   'uses' => 'ViewController@ViewMaker',
   'as' => 'products'
));

Route::post('products_filter', array(
   'uses' => 'PostController@ProductFilter',
   'as' = >'products_filter'
));
```

**ViewController** loads "products" page.
**PostController** filters the db query and makes "products" page

```
return view('products', ['$filtered_results' => filtered_results]);
```

Thanks in advance.